# Error unexpected token }, Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

When i click `click_profile_list` i get error

[image] or `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

[image]

```
function click_profile_list(choice, profileid, i_array) {
  if(choice==0) {
    alert("Profile",  i_array.firstname);
  }
  else {
    alert("Profile 2" , i_array.firstname);
  }
}

for(var key in msg.db) {
        var bypass = {
          firstname: msg.db[key].firstname, 
          lastname: msg.db[key].lastname,
          email: msg.db[key].user_email,
        };

        //html = '<div class="rows" onclick=click_profile_list(' + input + ',' + msg.db[key].id + ',' + bypass + ');>' ;
        html = '<div class="rows" onclick="click_profile_list(' + input + ',' + msg.db[key].id + ',' + bypass + ');">' ;
        html += msg.db[key].id  + ' - ';
        html += msg.db[key].firstname + ' - ';
        html += msg.db[key].lastname + ' - ';
        html += msg.db[key].fallback;
        html += '</div>' ;


        $('#show_list_window_body').append(html);
      }
```

**EDIT:** , is removed, onclick="function();" added

```
$('#show_list_window_body').html(html);
          for(var key in msg.db) {
            var bypass = {
              firstname: msg.db[key].firstname, 
              lastname: msg.db[key].lastname,
              email: msg.db[key].user_email
            };

            var tmp_id = 'iDontKnow' + msg.db[key].id;

            html = '<div class="rows" id="' + tmp_id + '">' ;
            html += msg.db[key].id  + ' - ';
            html += msg.db[key].firstname + ' - ';
            html += msg.db[key].lastname;
            html += '</div>' ;


            $('#show_list_window_body').append(html);
            let $elem = $("<div class='rows' id='" + tmp_id + "'>");
            $elem.click( () => click_profile_list(input, msg.db[key].id, bypass) );
          }
```

Comment: It seems your `object` is adding an extra `"` that breaks html, but to properly check your issue better create a MVCE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're inserting `bypass` into a String that is supposed to be HTML, but `bypass` is an object. You also just found out why this way of implementing what you want to do is bad and error-prone.

Comment: [`alert(message)`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert) only has one parameter not two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra comma at the end of your object :

```
var bypass = {
          firstname: msg.db[key].firstname, 
          lastname: msg.db[key].lastname,
          email: msg.db[key].user_email, // <-- Remove this comma
};
```

Then, add double quotes around your `onclick` function :

```
html = '<div class="rows" onclick="click_profile_list(' + input + ',' + msg.db[key].id + ',' + bypass + ');">'
```

Or (much) better, attach a click handler instead of inline javascript :

```
let $elem = $("<div class='rows'>")
$elem.click( () => click_profile_list(input, msg.db[key].id, bypass) )
```

```js
let $clickme = $("<div>Click me!</div>")
$clickme.click(() => alert("it works!"))

$("#main").append($clickme)
```

```css
#main * {
  font-size: x-large;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hjBmxg6Rth/ - I tried that now the error is gone but on click nothing happens, element on inspect do not show any onclick attachment: `<div class="rows" id="iDontKnow157">`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proper jQuery solution:

```js
const msg = {};
msg.db = {
  alice: {
    firstname: "Alice",
    lastname: "Bob",
    user_email: "alice@bob.com",
    id: 1,
    fallback: "fallback"
  },
  charlie: {
    firstname: "Charlie",
    lastname: "Delta",
    user_email: "charlie@delta.com",
    id: 2,
    fallback: "fallback2"
  }
};

function click_profile_list(e) {
  $el = $(e.target);
  var choice = 0; // get from whatever sets this
  var user = msg.db[$el.data("key")];

  if (choice == 0) {
    alert(user.firstname);
  }
}

var input = 0;

for (var key in msg.db) {
  var user = msg.db[key];
  $user = $("<div>").addClass("rows").data("key", key);
  $user.text([user.id, user.firstname, user.lastname, user.fallback].join(" - "));

  $('#show_list_window_body').append($user);
}

$('#show_list_window_body').on("click", ".rows", click_profile_list);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show_list_window_body"></div>
```

The list doesn't get awkward inline onclick code that tries to pass an object; instead each list item gets a `data-key` attribute referencing the database key. When clicked, the `key` is read back; this is used to grab the relevant data from the db.

Answer (score 0):

You have two syntactical mistakes. One in your JavaScript and one in the HTML markup you produce.

JS

```
var bypass = {
          firstname: msg.db[key].firstname, 
          lastname: msg.db[key].lastname,
          email: msg.db[key].user_email, // <--- here is your issue, you should not use a comma after the last object element
        };
```

HTML

```
html = '<div class="rows" onclick=click_profile_list(' + input + ',' + msg.db[key].id + ',' + bypass + ');>' ;
```

You must wrap the value of the attribute onclick with single or double quotes. In your code, just wrap it with double quotes `onclick="...;"`

Look [@Jeremy Thille's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48902590/645186) for a better way to do this.

Comment: Still getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` , where div had `onclick="click_profile_list([object Object]);"`